# Windows 7 doesn't boot; no device, invalid sig

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

Booting to Windows 7 has worked in the past. I don't know what changed.

When I select the Windows 7 menu item, I receive the errors:

```
no device
invalid signature 468CEF828CEF6ABF
```

Note that I've manually added the Win 7 option to GRUB, since GRUB has never been able to detect my Windows installation.

```
menuentry "Windows 7" {
  insmod ntfs
  set root='(hd0,1)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 468CEF828CEF6ABF
  chainloader +1
}
```

Help resolving this error (and possibly getting GRUB to properly detect Windows) would be great.

[Boot Info Script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11986950/) (it's too big to paste here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works again. I modified `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` like so:

```
menuentry "Windows 7" {
    insmod ntfs
    set root=(hd0,1)
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 468cef828cef6abf
    chainloader +1
}
```

Either the solution was this, or Windows simply didn't feel like booting the last time I tried.